# Go to page section after redirect

Tags: 7, users, redirection

I wanted to provide feature where non-logged in users can click on "Rate" button, which will lead them to login and after login they come back to the page. Upto this, it is working fine.

But I want user's to go to particular section of page, `div with id = "id1"`.

How can I achieve this?

-- Many thanks for your time.

This is what I have tried:

```
$destination = drupal_get_destination();

$options = array( 'query' => $destination,'fragment'=>'div_id');

print l('Review', 'content/login', $options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me...

```
$destination = drupal_get_destination();
$destination['destination'] .= '#div_id';
$options = array( 'query' => $destination);
print l('Review', 'content/login', $options);
```

Comment: No I setting just redirect url with fragment in it. This is my code:                          $destination = drupal_get_destination();
$options = array( 'query' =>   $destination,'fragment'=>'tabs-0-region_');
print l('Review', 'content/login', $options);

Comment: Edited question

Comment: Hmmm try adding it to the `$destination` variable, something like `$destination['path'] .= '#div_id';`

Comment: No luck, it didn't work.

Comment: Oops wrong array key, please see the updated answer

Comment: Actually, it replaced destination URl with #div_id only, and not working.

Comment: That code outputs: `<a href="/content/login?destination=devel/php%23div_id">Review</a>` which works perfectly for me...

Comment: Yes it is working. Actually, I don't notice concatenation. I was assigning.

Comment: Glad to help  :)